# Extend read-only C# Model with custom information

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-services, modeling

I have some design-problems based on a lack of best pratices. I have a given Model containing some user information that I cant change as I have read-only access via OData-Service-Call. For example:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set: }
}
```

Now I'm interested in adding some user-related information and save this information in a local database using EntityFramework. The final goal is to get an extended model like the following:

```
public class ExtendedUser
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set: }
    public char FavoriteChar { get; set; } // <-- additional Information
}
```

Because there are many users available and only a very few do have this additional Information (`FavoriteChar`) it might be a good idea to create another model for saving only the addiotional information. Espcially some values (e.g. email) might change and I do not want to sync those values all the time. So I thought about such a model:

```
public class FavoriteCharAssignment
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public char FavoriteChar { get; set; }
}
```

And now the tricky part: How do I *merge* those both models (`User` and `FavoriteCharAssignment`) to get the `ExtendedUser[]`?

```
Users[] users = odata.Users.ToArray();
using(db = new Context())
{
    FavoriteCharAssignment[] assignments =  db.FavoriteCharAssignments.ToArray();

    /*
     * Here I need some magic to merge those two arrays to an ExtendedUser[]  
     */ 
}
```

In SQL-words: I need to do a kindof cross-join between an OData-Serice and the EntityFramwork. :)

Comment: On the C# end, you'd normally sub-class `User`. The sub-class would contain the additional property `FavoriteChar`: `class ExtendedUser : User { public char FavoriteChar { get; set; } }`. The question would then be how to configure Entity Framework such that it maps the sub-class to/from a separate DB table (such as the one you're suggesting)?

Comment: I also thought about this solution. But I guess this woulnd't be possible as the base-class is provided via OData-Service and the sub-class must be stored in SQL via EF.